# access a public static variable from a library in a class (codeigniter controller)

Tags: php, class, variables, static

In codeigniter I have a library called integration in which at the top declaration I have a public static variable that holds an array as such:

```
public static $socialLogin = array(
    'twitter',
    'facebook',
    'google',
    'yahoo'
);
```

I am trying to access this in a controller, and I call the library in the controllers constructor via `$this->load->library('integration');` Then I try and access it in the following code snippet:

```
        foreach ($this->integration->socialLogin as $provider):
            if (!empty($_SESSION['jigowatt'][$provider])) {
                $this->_social_login($provider);
                break;
            }
        endforeach;
```

and recieve a `Undefined property: Integration::$socialLogin` as well as `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. How does one access a public static variable from a library in a controller?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking "what's wrong" and not a programming question as outlined in the help section.

Comment: i would disagree. but i changed the syntax just for you

Comment: You perhaps want to read about how to access static class variables (super global or super static variables): http://php.net/language.oop5.static (that is the detailed version) the normal version is here: http://www.php.net/language.oop5.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static properties must be accessed using the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), aka the double colon. For this, you'd use the class name directly, not the CI object's instance.

```
$providers = Integration::$socialLogin;
foreach ($providers as $provider) {
    ... 
}
```